# Gridster Position of current widget not saved in db when adding another widget and current widget moves down

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridster

I am using gridster.js. When i am adding a new widget,current widget moves down as per the requirement.But how and where can i get the changed position of the moved widget to save that in db?

Answer (score 0):

You can use serialize method to get widget positions. It returns a Array of objects that can be used as a JSON object.

```
gridster.serialize();
```

Sample output:

```
[{"col":1,"row":4,"size_x":2,"size_y":2},{"col":3,"row":1,"size_x":1,"size_y":2},{"col":4,"row":1,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":2,"row":6,"size_x":3,"size_y":1},{"col":1,"row":7,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":1,"row":6,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":2,"row":7,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":2,"row":8,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":4,"row":7,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":2,"row":1,"size_x":1,"size_y":3},{"col":1,"row":8,"size_x":1,"size_y":2},{"col":3,"row":7,"size_x":1,"size_y":2},{"col":4,"row":8,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":2,"row":9,"size_x":3,"size_y":1},{"col":5,"row":1,"size_x":1,"size_y":2},{"col":5,"row":3,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":3,"row":10,"size_x":1,"size_y":1}]
```

Demo [here](http://gridster.net/demos/serialize.html)

**Edit:**

```
gridster.serialize_changed() //Call this after adding the new widgets
```

To get the position of widgets with updated positions, you can use `.serialize_changed()` method. It returns an array of objects representing the current position of the widgets who have changed position.

Comment: Thanks for the information . But how do i get particular widget whose position got changed after adding a new widget .

Comment: `.serialize_changed()` returns the positions widgets whose position got changed. You can use that one. Or just collect the positions of widgets before adding the new widget and after. Now compare the two json array and find the widget with updated position.

Comment: I tried with serialize_changed(). But its returning no data. As per my understanding, with remove_widget we are setting this.$changed in gridster.js but for add_widget there is no such thing. So i am unable to get any data with serialize_changed() when adding . Please correct if I am wrong.